# Use a textbox to download files

Tags: forms, textbox

I am a teacher and I want students to be able to download their assignments after I have graded them. All the assignments are name "studentid.docx" so I was wondering if there was a way to create a textbox where students simply enter in their id, and it grabs their file. I just want to point it to a common directory, say mysite.com/assignment1/studentid.docx. Is this possible?

Comment: yes that would be easily possible. you have to write a small script which will read id entered in textbox and it will send that id using Ajax to server. Server will return the studentid.docs link which will be displayed below the textbox where clicking will enable student to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to append id to the string "student" from which you get the string "studentid" and then point to the file with the name as "studentid.docx" in the action attribute of you form whenever a student clicks submit button after entering his id in the form.

Comment: Are there any example codes I can modify? I'm not good working from scratch. :)

Comment: Javascript function to change action for form `function changeAction(){ document.forms[0].action = "mysite.com/Assignment1/student"+document.getElementById('idTextBox')+".docx";}` This should work.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have but it's not working:

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeAction(){ document.forms[0].action = "mysite.com/Assignment1/"+document.getElementById('idTextBox')+".docx";}
</script>
<form type="post">
<input type="text" id="idTextBox" size="25" />
<input type="submit" onClick="return changeAction();">
</form>`

Comment: This one is working for me I have added "student" in the path if you don't want it you can remove it You were using `type=post` but it should be either `method="get"` or `method="post"` `<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> function changeAction(){ 

document.forms[0].action = 

"mysite.com/Assignment1/Student"+document.getElementById('idTextBox').value

+".docx";} 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form method="get"> <input type="text" id="idTextBox" size="25" /> <input 

type="submit" onClick="return changeAction();"> </form>
</body>
</html>` Also please accept the answer if it works